# How to solve Magento 2 "Refuse to apply css because of its MIME type" on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, magento2.4.3, porto-theme

I have a `Magento 2` store and everything was ok with the default theme. Then I installed `Porto` theme and now I get this errors in the console and the page (especially the top menu) doesn't load properly:

```
The Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' does not support the source expression ''unsafe-inline''

Refused to apply style from 'https://example.com/media/porto/configed_css/settings_default.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

As a web server I'm using `Nginx`.

I tried running this commands after theme installation but I'm still getting the same errors:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Any ideas on what I could further do to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the CSS file in the "media" folder?

Comment: @MagePalExtensions no, the folder is empty